# Duplicating database with fluentd?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, fluentd

Good day everyone, is there a way or maybe a plugin that could send the content of a database to another database, basically duplicating it but with the use of fluentd?

Comment: Why do you need `fluentd` for this, specifically? It's not exactly intended for anything involving databases. And when you're talking about duplicating databases, do you mean real-time mirroring/replication? And what kind of database are we talking about here?

Comment: A database from a secure server to a database in Amazon Web Services, I was just asking because, in my understanding, I read that fluentd has many plugins, there are input plugins and output plugins, with the help of output plugins, they can place logs on a database, now, I just want to know actually is that, if fluentd has plugins for output to a database, is there a way that it can read from a database, and send that to another database? I'm just learning fluentd and I just want to know what more it can do. Sorry if my question seems useless :( please help me understand more.

Comment: If you have to replicate a database located 'on-premises' to AWS, there are recommended procedures for that, and it's recommended to use the features and tooling available in the database system to do so. What `fluentd` is really useful for is event/log capturing from multiple disparate systems and then storing them elsewhere (this could be a database, a search engine like Elasticsearch, or somewhere else) for processing. While there are a number of plugins and you could technically make it do what you want, I would not recommend it.

Comment: I had just read the plugins of fluentd and I believe what you say is correct, I haven't found any plugins that would probably read from a database and pass it, fluentd is entirely for event/log. So to answer my question, it is not recommended as @birryree had just said. Thank you sir for enlightening me :D